# Suggested pot size for fruit trees?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, containers, repotting, root-pruning

In different [orangeries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orangery) the pots for fruit trees (in particular citrus fruit) seem rather small compared to what some gardeners suggest, and also compared to the following [root ball table](https://www.vdberk.co.uk/advice/root-ball-table/). **What special treatment do the trees have to receive in order to healthly live in pots for their entire life?** Are the roots cutted every few years? Is there some rule of thumb between root size and tree top size, or stem circumference, or any other parameter?

I am particularly interested for common fruit trees like apple, pear, plum, but also lemon, orange or mulberry trees.

[image: Root ball table]